# 3d object with transparrent material shows as solid black

Tags: unity-game-engine, transparency

My guns have a certain range. When hovering over one I want to demonstrate what that means. So I've added a 3d-object (a flattened cylinder) which I want to show/hide onMouse-enter/leave.

But first I need it to be transparent - I've searched and found how - It's materials rendering mode must be transparent, and the color must have an alpha value (here 128).
[image]
But it looks VERY SOLID BLACK to me...?

Comment: Did you try to set it to `Fade` instead? also this looks quite violet since blue background + semi-transparent red might result in dark violet maybe?

Comment: Thanks, but that makes no difference - and it's not the combined color either - in the game-window it's really solid opaque black.. (The intended color: See the material-header-dot)

Comment: The only thing that works a little is if I select Shader: Sprites/Diffuse - that makes it transparent - but still BLACK.

Comment: Weird(?) I just changed (and saved) something unrelated in a script connected to the tower, and voila the RangeShow now has the correct color in the Game-window (still black in Scene-window..)

Comment: yeah the important one always is the GameView .. some shaders are not drawn correctly in the SceneView

Comment: @derHugo Did not know that :O, hope ill never meet with this fenomeno